# Can you forward declare an explicit specialization of undeclared template class?

Tags: c++, templates, cuda

In the class I am currently writing, I consider it to be very important that most of its private member variables remain `const`. As such, I have opted to use an initialization object that is not fully declared in the header file:

```cpp
// foo.h

template<typename T>
class Foo {
    const int *const memberVariable; // Important detail: pointer to a heap-allocated array
    const int otherMemberVariable;
    ...

    Foo(class FooInitializer &&initializer);

public:
    Foo(int constructorArgument, ...);
}

// foo.cpp

class FooInitializer {
    int *memberVariable; // Important detail: pointer to a heap-allocated array
    int otherMemberVariable;
    ...

    FooInitializer(int constructorArgument, ...) : memberVariable(constructorArgument, ...), ... {
        cuda_function(&memberVariable, &otherMemberVariable, ..., constructorArgument, ...);
        ...
    }
}

Foo::Foo(FooInitializer &&initializer) : memberVariable(std::move(initializer.memberVariable)), ... {}

Foo::Foo(int constructorArgument, ...) : Foo({constructorArgument, ...}) {}
```

However, this seems to break down if one of the constructor arguments or member variables must be of the type parameter type:

```cpp
// foo.h

template<typename T>
class Foo {
    const int *const memberVariable; // Important detail: pointer to a heap-allocated array
    const int otherMemberVariable;
    ...

    Foo(class FooInitializer<T> &&initializer);

public:
    Foo(int constructorArgument, ...);
}

// foo.cpp

template<typename T>
class FooInitializer {
    int *memberVariable;
    int otherMemberVariable;
    ...

    FooInitializer(int constructorArgument, ...) : memberVariable(constructorArgument, ...), ... {
        cuda_function(&memberVariable, &otherMemberVariable, ..., constructorArgument, ...);
        ...
    }
}

template<typename T>
Foo<T>::Foo(FooInitializer<T> &&initializer) : memberVariable(std::move(initializer.memberVariable)), ... {}

template<typename T>
Foo<T>::Foo(int constructorArgument, ...) : Foo({constructorArgument, ...}) {}
```

I have tried some alternative syntaxes (such as `Foo<T>::Foo(template<> FooInitializer<T> &&initializer)` to no avail. I am opposed to temporary heap allocation, and I am trying to avoid introducing `FooInitializer` into the header's namespace due to essentially duplicate declarations of the member variables. I was considering the possibility of storing a `const FooInitializer` instance itself as the only member variable of `Foo`, but unfortunately that would make variables like `memberVariable` in the example above `int *const`, not `const int *const`. They cannot be C++ containers because they are allocated in device memory by CUDA functions.

Is there an alternative approach I have not considered?

Comment: What does "this seems to break down" mean? Not compile? Not run as you expect?

Comment: @talonmies it does not compile.

Comment: I don't see any compiler errors in your question. Should we all guess what might be happening?

Comment: *"They cannot be C++ containers because they are allocated in device memory by CUDA functions"*. Can't you write your own if there are no libraries?

Comment: @Jarod42 That approach is unfortunately non-trivial, as I would need to replace all instances of `cudaStream_t` with a `shared_ptr` to keep the stream safety features I have implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Foo(class FooInitializer<T> &&initializer);`

Whereas you can declare (non-template) classes inside function declaration (`int bar(struct S s);`), I don't think you can for template classes.

> I am trying to avoid introducing `FooInitializer` into the header's namespace due to essentially duplicate declarations of the member variables.

but you can still **forward** declare the class:

```
template <typename> class FooInitializer;

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
    // ...
    Foo(FooInitializer<T> &&initializer);
    // ...
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Gjvh1P313)

Comment: I would have preferred to not forward declare the class in the header's namespace, but it seems this is the closest possible solution.

Comment: You can have it as inner class of `Foo`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fnfKrcE39)

Comment: That is what I ended up going with. Thank you!